# Connecting to ELM327 over Bluetooth (Android)

Tags: android, bluetooth, obd-ii, elm327

I am trying to write a simple app (similar to the BluetoothChat example) that will communicate with ELM327 (BT).

Torque (well known Android OBD app) is able to connect OK - its the only one. Neither my test app, nor SENA BTerm, nor android-obd-reader (well-known open source OBD app) is able to connect.

I am using the well-known service UUID 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

While the logs show the ACL_CONNECTED event, my code (and android-obd-reader) throws an IOException saying "socket closed or timeout".

These are the logs from my running my test just after calling connect.

```
01-10 11:44:44.094: D/DRD(7313): About to connect
01-10 11:44:44.094: W/BluetoothAdapter(7313): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
01-10 11:44:44.094: D/BTIF_SOCK(1311): service_uuid: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
01-10 11:44:44.104: D/BluetoothSocket(7313): connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[62]}
01-10 11:44:44.114: E/MP-Decision(1374): UP Ld:34 Nw:1.990000 Tw:140 rq:3.500000 seq:147.000000
01-10 11:44:44.945: E/MP-Decision(1374): DOWN Ld:10 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 rq:0.000000 seq:217.000000
01-10 11:44:45.856: W/bt-btif(1311): info:x0
01-10 11:44:45.856: D/(1311): remote version info [00:19:5d:26:d7:51]: 3, 7b, 229
01-10 11:44:45.866: D/btif_config_util(1311): btif_config_save_file(L153): in file name:/data/misc/bluedroid/bt_config.new
01-10 11:44:45.896: I/BluetoothConnectionReceiver(7920): onReceive(context, Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED flg=0x8000010 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.search.core.service.BluetoothConnectionReceiver (has extras) }, 00:19:5D:26:D7:51)
01-10 11:44:45.966: W/bt-sdp(1311): process_service_search_attr_rsp
01-10 11:44:45.976: E/bt-btif(1311): DISCOVERY_COMP_EVT slot id:90, failed to find channle,                                       status:1, scn:0
01-10 11:44:45.976: W/bt-btif(1311): invalid rfc slot id: 90
01-10 11:44:45.976: D/DRD(7313): connectDevice():java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

Any explanations? I would have put this down to a bad adapter, except that Torque works

Comment: Hello - It turns out this issue is seen only on my Cyanogen devices. And its not specific to OBD or ELM327; instead it affects all BT SPP connections. I don't know the reason, but for all those on Cyanogen devices, hopefully this helps.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249603/making-successful-bluetooth-connections-in-android for a resolution to this. However I need an explanation for why (A) works but not (B).