# Making successful Bluetooth connections in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-4.4-kitkat, cyanogenmod

I am mystified by two approaches to making BT connections in Android.

This is what I have done for as long as I can remember, and it has worked from 2.3+ devices to early 4.x. This what the [Android docs describe](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html) as well.

```
private static final UUID sppUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
bluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(sppUUID);
bluetoothSocket.connect();
```

This has ceased to work on some newer Androids (Nexus 7 running 4.4), Cyanogenmod with this result (or similar):

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

After much thrashing around--much of it in SO!--I find this works

```
Method m = bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
bluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(bluetoothDevice, 1);
bluetoothSocket.connect();
```

Where does this come from? Why does this work over the other approach?

Thank you

Comment: do you want communication in text or sending file connections..??
there should be same UUID. Check this [BluetoothChatApp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/25b6aed7b2e01ce7bdc0dfa1a79eaf009ad178fe/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatService.java)